# python: struct pack size longer than expected -- why does this happen?

Tags: python

So I want to pack a list of tuples and then unpack it later.

```
from struct import *
from itertools import chain
a = [(1, 67), (213, 455), (9009, 8887)]
# converts 3x2 list to 6x1 list
b = list(chain(*a))   
size=6
qq = pack('h'+'L'*size,size,*b)
# peak to get the list length
mysize = unpack('h',qq[:2])  
mysize = mysize[0]
unpack('L',qq[2:6])    
unpack('h'+'L'*mysize,qq)
unpack('L'*mysize, qq[2:])   # does not work
unpack('L'*mysize, qq[2:2+mysize*4])  # works
```

Using Python 2.7, the second to last line does not work.  I tested `len(qq)`, which is 28, when I was expecting 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html):

*C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and properly aligned by skipping pad bytes if necessary (according to the rules used by the C compiler)*.

Since you are running on a 64 bit machine, smaller types such as `h` and `L` are padded to 8 bytes. You can use the formatting flags `=, <, >, !` to remove the padding. For instance, adding "=" works

```
from struct import *
from itertools import chain
a = [(1, 67), (213, 455), (9009, 8887)]
# converts 3x2 list to 6x1 list
b = list(chain(*a))   
size=6
qq = pack('=h'+'L'*size,size,*b)
# peak to get the list length
mysize = unpack('=h',qq[:2])  
mysize = mysize[0]
unpack('=L',qq[2:6])    
unpack('=h'+'L'*mysize,qq)
unpack('=' + 'L'*mysize, qq[2:])   # does not work
unpack('=' + 'L'*mysize, qq[2:2+mysize*4])  # works
```